# "We" when referring to a team of 1

Tags: grammaticality, pronouns

When contacting different departments of companies many will end an email/letter with something like

> Sincerely,
>
> The [Company Name] Support **Team**.

additionally they will refer to themselves as "we"

> **We** don't have any further information on this.
>
> **We** are working on a fix.

---

If the team/company/department consists of 1 person, would it be ok to refer to yourself as a *team* and *we*?

Comment: It's a little bit pretentious to use the 'royal we' or 'ministerial we' in the more trivial context of an individual in a company. 'In my department, I am doing such and such' would be one way of expressing a solitary situation.

Comment: Generally it sounds silly and can be pretentious when it is obvious it is an individual. However, I think it is very common when a person/company wishes to expand in the future or wants to present themselves as larger than they are (but they have to really keep up appearances!).

Comment: @BobtheMagicMoose The intention, in this case, I don't think is pretentious. It's more to sound professional. One person department doesn't sound as profession as a department with many people.

Comment: But yes in any case it could be perceived as deceptive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is generally accepted to use *we* when the person represents the company and speaks for it. If the department consists of only one person, this person may still be said to represent the entire company in correspondence and she could thus use *we*.

If, however, there is really no conceivable group for which this person is speaking, she should technically not use *we*. Nevertheless, when this company of one is new or struggling, she might wish to pretend to be larger than she really is, in which case this minor infraction is probably a venial offence against truth. So I wouldn't really worry about it too much.

*Department* is fine in any case, as it does not indicate a number. The old metaphor *team*, literally "a set of draft beasts", is a cliché, generally not recommended by style books, so this would seem like an appropriate situation in which to dump it.

Comment: 'Team' is disparaged by style books? Which ones?

Comment: @Mitch: The participial phrase applies to the nominal group immediately before it, *a cliché*. Clichés are generally not recommended. In sports, the metaphor is perhaps now old and dead enough that it won't startle pedants any more. But surely not in commercialese?

Comment: Oh, clichés in general?  Not all metaphors are cliché, but anyway, it's been a dead  as a metaphor in sports since forever, and the metaphor for teamwork in a business, while much newer, is based on sports and if not dead is in hospice.

Comment: @Mitch: Of course not all metaphors are clichés, why would you say that? The metaphor in commercialese is ugly and unnecessary. Pedants hate it.

Comment: Cerb, pedants are often not found in commercial businesses. QED

Comment: @Mitch: Mitch, there are plenty of pedants in commercial businesses. And even more have to receive such e-mails. The step from a team of horses pulling a chariot to a team of football players playing together to win a prize is fine. But...

Comment: I hear team all the time in the legal/ business world,  it's a great way to express intradepartmental unity and identity,  it also connotes a flat organizational structure. Few people use draft beasts on a daily or even yearly basis and I would agree that that definition is pretty much on life support.

Comment: @BobtheMagicMoose: Nevertheless, it's aesthetically deficient.